# AWS CloudFrontを使ってhttps化したい

Tags: aws

・CloudFrontでS3のウェブサイトをSSL化する
https://qiita.com/jasbulilit/items/73d70a01a5d3b520450f

上記を参考に証明書の発行は完了しています。

・CloudFront で S3 静的ウェブサイトホスティングを SSL/TLS に対応させる
https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/tls-for-s3-web-hosting-with-cloudfront/

の手続きを行ったのですが何故かhttps://xxx.comが「サーバが見つかりません」と表示されます。
（その前まではhttp://でアクセスできました。）

https://xxx.cloudfront.net はアクセスできてhttps化されています。

cloudfront.netから.comに飛ばしたいです。

何が原因わかる方いますでしょうか。
ドメインはお名前.comで取得、Route53で各レコード追加ています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: xxx.com を正引きした場合と、xxx.cloudfront.net を正引きした場合で IPアドレスは一致してますか？

Answer (score 0):

SSL通信のためのポートは開いていますでしょうか。通常は443ポートになります。